# C automatic variables

Tags: c

I'm designing 2 functions, I'm trying to be sure I doing correctly. The idea is that in the first function , a struct pointer is created and passed to a function that might or might not fill the said struct. In the event the struct is not filled I was hoping that the pointer in the first function would get removed by automatic variable rule. Will this result in code that is difficult to understand or maintain?

Here is first function :

```
static void read_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    /* This callback is invoked when there is data to read on bev. */

    struct header_t *header;.

    int result;
    result = checkForHeader(bev, header);

    if (result == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // More code here...
    // Here would be safe to assume header is filled and usable...
}
```

and here is second / filling function :

```
int checkForHeader(struct bufferevent *bev, header_t *header) {

    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);

    size_t buffer_len = evbuffer_get_length(input);
    ev_uint32_t record_len;

    if (buffer_len < CS_HEADER_SIZE)
        return 0; /* The size field hasn't arrived. */

    // We have an actual header (parsing)
    header = calloc(1, sizeof(*header));

    if (!header) {
        perror("calloc");
        return 0;
    }
    header->filled = 1; // Just an example.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @Snowman, MAthv, the code does **not** make sense.  you passed the **value** of `header` (which is a pointer) to `checkForHeader()`.  that value is garbage.  you need to pass the address of that pointer if you're relying on `checkForHeader()` to allocate the space for the actual struct of type `header_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter header is a local variable in the second function. Whatever you store in it will be lost when the function returns. Since you stored a pointer to memory allocated with calloc, that pointer is lost, and the allocated memory stays allocated forever without any possibility to ever use it or free it.

Comment: 2nd parameter to 2nd function is header_t pointer header. I guess you made a point here that it might be confusing for any other reader.

Comment: I don't think you get what gnasher729 is saying .. you are passing an uninitialized variable `header` to `checkForHeader()`. It is ignoring the passed-in value and overwriting the _local_ copy with the result of `calloc()`. Nothing is returning that pointer to the calling function.

Comment: Yep , After a cup of coffee, I do get it now.